# How to get entities from table by name and another multiple nullable parameters from SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am making small e-shop for fun and want to filter results from searching entities by name and/or filter. If name is empty or null, it will get all entities (that works fine), but if I want filter it by category or discount or if its new (always just one filter and/or name), it ignores that completely. How to search it by name, by name and filter, or just filter correctly?

Code is here:

```sql
DECLARE @Name       AS VARCHAR(100) = '',
        @CategoryId AS INT          = null,
        @IsNew      AS BIT          = 0,
        @IsDiscount AS BIT          = 0;

SELECT
    *
FROM
    Products P
WHERE
    (P.Name COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI LIKE '%' + COALESCE( @Name, '' ) + '%')
    AND (P.CategoryId = @CategoryId OR P.New = @IsNew 
         OR IIF(P.PriceDiscount IS NULL, 0, 1) = @IsDiscount)
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: _"it ignores that completly. How to search it by name, by name and filter, or just filter correctly?"_ - by **not** trying to have dynamic criteria with tricks like `IIF( P.PriceDiscount IS NULL, 0, 1) = @IsDiscount` : its an anti-pattern that doesn't work (for many reasons I won't get into - and `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` doesn't scale). Unfortunately SQL/T-SQL (still) does not support any kind of true optional predicates - I find what works for me is to have different versions of a query (with different criteria and parameters) that are invoked with `IF` logic at the `PROCEDURE`-level.

Comment: Another option is to change optional equality predicate to a mandatory range predicate (with the range using universally inclusive values when the criteria should be ignored). I use this option a lot too.

Comment: `'%' + COALESCE( @Name, '' ) + '%'` <-- This is redundant because  (based on your code) `@name` will never be `NULL` (also, use `ISNULL` instead of `COALESCE` in SQL Server because only `ISNULL` changes the nullability of an expression, `COALESCE` does not.

Comment: I forgot to tell, that its originally code from stored procedure and there can be everything null, its just working code in query where I want to add filtration not just by name, the idea of multiple queries invoke by `IF` sounds good, thanks

Comment: _"...its originally code from stored procedure and there can be everything `NULL`"_ <-- I died inside somewhat.